# How can i change server date on jelastic server? (nginx)

Tags: datetime, jelastic

I want change server datetime on jelastic server.
It need me for cron job.

Answer (score 0):

This operation can be done only from the Hosting Provider side.
So contact your Hosting Provider Support and ask them to do it.

[image: Support]